# If $\lim f'(x) = 0$, then $\lim f(x+1) - f(x) = 0$

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Let $f: \mathbb R \to (E,||\cdot||)$, where $(E,||\cdot||)$ is a normed linear space. Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ and that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f'(x) = 0$. Prove that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x+1) - f(x) = 0$.

In the simple case $E = \mathbb R$, this can be shown by MVT. In some other particular cases I can prove this as well. But I cannot see how this might be done in an arbitrary $E$: I do not have any relevant theorems as tools.

Any hints or suggestions?

Comment: Let $F$ be the completion of $E$. Then $f: \mathbb R \to F$ and you can use the deleted answer...

Comment: @N.S.: Thank you; I was not able to find a reason to convince the OP of this. Feel free to post an answer :)

Comment: @GudsonChou, you didn't even try to convince me. You automatically deleted your answer.

Comment: @BolzWeir As I said, I was not able to figure out a reason to convince you; then silence is the best policy... :) I am not a native English speaker, so perhaps sometimes my use of language is not precise enough for the native ears...

Comment: Moreover, considering your seemingly overbearing tone, I would delete my answer even if I was able to give a suitable reason.

Comment: @GudsonChou: usually, when you say that were not able to convince someone with a fact, it is understood that the fact is known to you, but the other person is just not getting it. In other words, that you have tried to explain the idea to the other person, but he did not catch up. Hence my overbearing tone. It turns out it was just a misunderstanding.